# Replace code with a variable Python

Tags: python

I have a program in which part of its code has to be modified constantly:

```
VAR = 'math.sin(x*y)*math.sin(x*y)'

while (x <=  vfinal) and (y <= vfinal):
    v1 = bm.verts.new((round(x,3),round(y,3),VAR))
    x = x + precision
    v2 = bm.verts.new((round(x,3),round(y,3),VAR))
    y = y + precision
    x = x - precision
    v3 = bm.verts.new((round(x,3),round(y,3),VAR))
    x = x + precision
    v4 = bm.verts.new((round(x,3),round(y,3),VAR))
    bm.faces.new((v1,v2,v4,v3))
    y = y - precision
    if (round(x,1) == vfinal):
        y = y + precision
        x = vinicial
```

Since `math.sin(x*y)*math.sin(x*y)` appears 4 times (possibly more once I expand the program), I want to easily change the program by changing whats stored in `VAR`.

So far I tried making VAR a string, which gives an error because `bm.verts.new` wont accept strings. Also tried removing the ' ' in VAR, to make it a number, but this won't give the desired result further down because `x` and `y` change constantly. The only thing that worked was writing math.sin(x*y)*math.sin(x*y) 4 times, but its tedious and im lazy.

Is there any way to do what I want? if not, what should I do?

Comment: Why wouldn't you put it in a function, and change the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to dynamically execute code, you can make `VAR` a function:

```
VAR = lambda x, y: math.sin(x * y) * math.sin(x * y)
```

or if you prefer a vanilla function:

```
def VAR(x, y):
    return math.sin(x * y) * math.sin(x * y)
```

You can then reuse the logic by calling the function. For example:

```
v1 = bm.verts.new((round(x,3),round(y,3),VAR(x, y)))
```

Comment: Might suggest a PEP-8-compliant name -- and maybe a longer-form definition.

Comment: @kindall Yes thanks, I was in the process of updating

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, you're probably right. I was going to suggest that but was hesitant to modify the OP's code to much with explaining why. I'll update.

Comment: Tried doing that, now I get TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'

Comment: @tacofisher Sorry, forgot to pass `x` and `y` to `VAR`. Now it should work.

Comment: Great, nice to hear @tacofisher. If this answer helped you, [consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).